# Could we get a version of The Key for our favorite site?

Tags: feature-request, fun, april-fools

The Key looks really great and all, but I noticed that it is Stack Overflow-specific - it's logo is that of Stack Overflow rather than Stack Exchange or any of our other specific sites.

I'm working on my Ultimate Gaming Console and would really like a version of The Key with the Arqade logo so I can feel empowered as I copypaste cheat codes and fill clan chat with spam.

*Could we please allow orders of The Key to request a different site logo than Stack Overflow?*

Comment: Yawn. What plz?

Comment: I suspect you can expect it in 6 to 8 weeks

Comment: I think it would be better to be able to order The Key with extra keys for each stack you want to use it on. So, if you want to use it on three stacks, you should be able to order The Key that has five buttons: [stack overflow] [arqade] [cooking] [c] [v]

Comment: [someone](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/1377615767731048452?s=19) got just now=P

Answer (score 12):

While the initial plan for The Key was to focus on Stack Overflow, we definitely believe that it has broader appeal across the network.

Here are some examples I thought of off the top of my head in addition to your suggestion for Arqade:

- Every great info sec specialist also finds it regularly necessary to copy guidance from [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) into their company policies!
- [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) is a prime source for great legal information to add to an amicus brief along with [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/) for your patent documentation.
- [Chemists](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/), [Biologists](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) and [Mathematicians](https://math.stackexchange.com/) could all benefit from having a The Key for accessing their related subject sites
- Film, TV and book reviewers frequently copy from sites like [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/), [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/), and [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) while authors take liberal guidance from [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) and [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/)!

While we're still in early planning, do keep an ear out for future developments in these directions!

If you can think of value to a site I haven't mentioned, please share so that we can consider that site's need for The Key, too!

Comment: Gardeners to copy plants found on Gardening and Landscaping. DIY enthusiast to copy building plans to their own houses. Electrical Engineers to copy schematics to construct their newest keyboards

Comment: Will there be a camera-ready version of The Key for students to post cell phone-quality pictures of their exam questions directly to Biology Stack Exchange?